# Why do .ftl file are exactly same have different file size?

Tags: freemarker, filesize

I have two ftl files that are exactly same (in terms of the content of the file and file name) but differ by quite a margin on file size. One file is 9502 bytes while the other is 9647 kbps. The only difference I can see is the files are located in different folders. I don't know why there is such a small difference. Is there some sort of history or something that is stored with the file that is not visible to the user? If so, how would you delete this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's no trailing whitespace that's visible just hard to spot, then my guess is that the longer file uses CRLF (Windows convention) for line breaks, while the shorter uses LF (UN*X convention). Some text editors, like Notepad++, has modes that show that. And it's not a FreeMarker thing, it's just a text file thing. There's no hidden history or hidden anything that's FreeMarker-specific.